# Do I need to encrypt mysql rows while storing HIPPA Compliance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, security, encryption, amazon-rds

I have an application which has PHI(Protected Healthcare Information) and hence it has to be HIPPA compliant.I am using AWS and have RDS which has encryption enabled at rest.

However, we are also encrypting the data in mysql while storing the patient information. For example patient name 'Dorian' will be first encrypted using AES encryption and then will be stored. In this way if someone as access to the database(which is not possible but still in worst case), he can not read the patient information.

The problem is that its very difficult to search usual mysql queries in such encrypted data, so I cant to select patient where name="Dorian" because the string stored in DB is encrypted hash.

My question is :

1. Is it required to store the encrypted value on table level in addition of having RDS encryption enabled at rest? (I have no access of RDS outside VPC)
2. Is there any way I can have mysql encryption on table level also, but I can efficiently do the normal where queries? I am keeping in mind that data can get very large in few months.

Comment: This is a legal question. Legal questions tend to be closed really quickly on here because nobody wants to be liable for giving legal advice publicly. If you read the HIPAA Compliance whitepaper published by Amazon, it answers your question on page 8 in the **Amazon RDS for MySQL** section: https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/compliance/AWS_HIPAA_Compliance_Whitepaper.pdf You should really read that whitepaper before implementing a HIPAA solution on AWS anyway.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about legal compliance, not programming.

Comment: I appreciate your response. Thanks :)